# Scheduling Mysql procedure/macro to load CSV data

Tags: mysql

As I'm beginner to mysql ,I'm asking this question. Please help me.

I had .csv file and i'm loading this file data into mysql table. using the following command

"load data infile 'D:/xampp/htdocs/test/test.csv' into table offers fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n' ignore 1 rows; "

It is inserting data into data into table successfully.

Now my question as follows

1. test.csv file(it has a huge volume of data)is going to update for every 24 hours. So that I want a stored procedure/macro( whatever it may be) to load the updated data into offers table it is going to call for every 24 hours, So that table data is in sync with .csv file.

   Steps to remember

   1. I want to truncate the offers table data before insert into table
   2. and load the data using above command
   3. Create a success log status in another log table(optional)

I heared that "load data" not going to work in stored procedure (I don't exactly).please give me any answer/suggesstions.

Comment: What OS are you running this on?

Comment: I'm Using Windows 10 64bit OS.